# reveals.js : how to reduce space on top of slides?

Tags: reveal.js

I am new using reveal.js.

I did not manage to reduce the space on top of my slides. Could somebody help me ?

Note : I a am using `pandoc` to create my slideshow from Markdown sources. This is the command line I use :

```
pandoc -s -f markdown+tex_math_single_backslash \
       --bibliography=bibliography.bib --filter pandoc-citeproc \
       --slide-level 2 --toc --mathjax -i -t revealjs -V theme:beige \
       -H mysettings.css mfront.md -o mfront.html
```

This is generated code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="generator" content="pandoc">
    <meta name="author" content="Thomas Helfer" />
    <meta name="dcterms.date" content="2014-01-01" />
    <title>MFront User Meeting: TFEL 2.0 and beyond</title>
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="reveal.js/css/reveal.min.css"/>
    <style type="text/css">code{white-space: pre;}</style>
    <style type="text/css">
      table.sourceCode, tr.sourceCode, td.lineNumbers, td.sourceCode {
      margin: 0; padding: 0; vertical-align: baseline; border: none; }
      table.sourceCode { width: 100%; line-height: 100%; }
      td.lineNumbers { text-align: right; padding-right: 4px; padding-left: 4px; color: #aaaaaa; border-right: 1px solid #aaaaaa; }
      td.sourceCode { padding-left: 5px; }
      code > span.kw { color: #007020; font-weight: bold; }
      code > span.dt { color: #902000; }
      code > span.dv { color: #40a070; }
      code > span.bn { color: #40a070; }
      code > span.fl { color: #40a070; }
      code > span.ch { color: #4070a0; }
      code > span.st { color: #4070a0; }
      code > span.co { color: #60a0b0; font-style: italic; }
      code > span.ot { color: #007020; }
      code > span.al { color: #ff0000; font-weight: bold; }
      code > span.fu { color: #06287e; }
      code > span.er { color: #ff0000; font-weight: bold; }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="reveal.js/css/theme/simple.css" id="theme">
    <!-- If the query includes 'print-pdf', include the PDF print sheet -->
    <script>
      if( window.location.search.match( /print-pdf/gi ) ) {
      var link = document.createElement( 'link' );
      link.rel = 'stylesheet';
      link.type = 'text/css';
      link.href = 'reveal.js/css/print/pdf.css';
      document.getElementsByTagName( 'head' )[0].appendChild( link );
      }
    </script>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="reveal.js/lib/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
      .reveal h1 { font-size: 2.5em; }
      .reveal section img {
      border: none;
      box-shadow: none;
      }
      body {
      background: url("images/background.svg") no-repeat fixed top left
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="reveal">
      <div class="slides">
</section><section id="logarithmic-strains---principle" class="slide level2">
  <h1>Logarithmic strains - Principle</h1>
  <ul>
    <li class="fragment"><span class="math">\({\underline{T}}\)</span> is the dual of the logarithmic strain <span class="math">\({\underline{\epsilon}^{\mathrm{to}}}{}_{\text{log}}\)</span>
      <ul>
    <li class="fragment"><span class="math">\(P={\underline{T}}\,\colon\,{\underline{\epsilon}^{\mathrm{to}}}{}_{\text{log}}={\underline{S}}\,\colon\,{\underline{\epsilon}^{\mathrm{to}}}{}_{\text{GL}}\)</span></li>
    </ul></li>
    <li class="fragment">if the small strain behaviour is <strong>thermodynamically consistent</strong>, so does the corresponding finite strain behaviour.</li>
    <li class="fragment">the behaviour is <strong>objective</strong> due to its lagrangian nature.</li>
    <li class="fragment"><strong>no restriction</strong> on the small strain behaviour (initial and induced <strong>orthotropy</strong> can be handled appropriately: application to Zircaloy ?)
      <ul>
    <li class="fragment">much more appealing than the hypoelastic <a href="http://www-cast3m.cea.fr/">Cast3M</a> formulation</li>
    </ul></li>
    <li class="fragment"><em>drawbacks:</em> the pre- and post-processing stage are non trivial and may have a significant computation costs.</li>
    <li class="fragment"><span class="math">\({\underline{T}}\)</span> is the dual of the logarithmic strain <span class="math">\({\underline{\epsilon}^{\mathrm{to}}}{}_{\text{log}}\)</span>
      <ul>
    <li class="fragment"><span class="math">\(P={\underline{T}}\,\colon\,{\underline{\epsilon}^{\mathrm{to}}}{}_{\text{log}}={\underline{S}}\,\colon\,{\underline{\epsilon}^{\mathrm{to}}}{}_{\text{GL}}\)</span></li>
    </ul></li>
    <li class="fragment"><span class="math">\({\underline{T}}\)</span> is the dual of the logarithmic strain <span class="math">\({\underline{\epsilon}^{\mathrm{to}}}{}_{\text{log}}\)</span>
      <ul>
    <li class="fragment"><span class="math">\(P={\underline{T}}\,\colon\,{\underline{\epsilon}^{\mathrm{to}}}{}_{\text{log}}={\underline{S}}\,\colon\,{\underline{\epsilon}^{\mathrm{to}}}{}_{\text{GL}}\)</span></li>
    </ul></li>
  </ul>
</section></section></section>
</div>
</div>
<script src="reveal.js/lib/js/head.min.js"></script>
<script src="reveal.js/js/reveal.min.js"></script>
<script>

  // Full list of configuration options available here:
  // https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js#configuration
  Reveal.initialize({
  controls: true,
  progress: true,
  history: true,
  center: true,
  theme: 'beige', // available themes are in /css/theme
  transition: Reveal.getQueryHash().transition || 'default', // default/cube/page/concave/zoom/linear/fade/none

  // Optional libraries used to extend on reveal.js
  dependencies: [
  { src: 'reveal.js/lib/js/classList.js', condition: function() { return !document.body.classList; } },
  { src: 'reveal.js/plugin/zoom-js/zoom.js', async: true, condition: function() { return !!document.body.classList; } },
  { src: 'reveal.js/plugin/notes/notes.js', async: true, condition: function() { return !!document.body.classList; } },
  //          { src: 'reveal.js/plugin/search/search.js', async: true, condition: function() { return !!document.body.classList; }, }
  //          { src: 'reveal.js/plugin/remotes/remotes.js', async: true, condition: function() { return !!document.body.classList; } }
  ]});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This leads to a slide title under a significant margin and parts of the slide hidden.

Comment: Post some code please

Answer (score 2):

reveal.js has a "height" option that can be set when you call Reveal.initialize.

With pandoc, provided you have a recent templates/default.revealjs, you can set the "height" variable:

```
---
author: me
title my title
height: 800
...

my presentation
```